# Customizing UIButton class' behavior in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm beginner ObjC-developer and I've stumbled over following problem:
I'm writing some project for iOS7 and I have customize UIButton class to make it changing it's size on touch event (shrinking on touch down, growing on touch up).
By now I'm using following technique:
I've linked every button's touch events with IBAction like this one:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTouchDown:(id)sender {
    [self shrinkButton:sender];
}
```

and then I'm modifying sender's constraints in specified method.
But I'm going to use such button in many places so I find duplicating IBAction for every occurrence of a button as very inefficient way.
What are possible solutions of this problem? I do not even know if I have to use composition or inheritance.
BTW operating with constraints is preferable rather than view's frame since I'm dealing with iOS7.
Hope you can help me.

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't implement this behavior in a UIButton's subclass. The button usually is a "view" when you see it through the MVC optic and should not implement a behavior. Use a controller instead.

Comment: @BrunoKoga That would needlessly complicate things. This is still code that handles the inner working of the view. Much like you would put the drawing code of a view inside the view's implementation, so should inner working of views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `UIButton` subclass, which implements the functionality above. On `init`, `initWithFrame:` and `initWithCoder:` add `self` as target for the touch up and touch down events, giving the corresponding selector. Now you can use this subclass in interface builder as your buttons' classes.

Comment: Thanks, @leo-natan! May I also ask: is such code correct? `[self addTarget:self action:@selector(shrinkButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];`